# Update single column of different data types

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, updates

I have three tables in Oracle database:
CONTENT, CONTENT_DATA , DATA_TYPE

Data records in CONTENT_DATA are as follows:

```
PK_ID  DATA_TYPE_ID  CONTENT_ID   VALUE
1         1             1           0
2         2             1          100
3         3             1          200
```

I need to update 'value' column to sum of other 'value' columns according to their DATA_TYPE_ID in CONTENT_DATA table and this process should be done for each of CONTENT_ID.
For example: VALUE(DATA_TYPE(3)) = SUM(VALUE(DATA_TYPE(1)), VALUE(DATA_TYPE(2)))

I created the procedure which is shown below. But it runs very slow. Are there any better option to handle such a problem?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_DATA
AS
    CURSOR your_cursor is
        SELECT DISTINCT CONTENT_ID FROM CONTENT_DATA;
    item your_cursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
    OPEN your_cursor;
    loop
        FETCH your_cursor INTO item;
        UPDATE CONTENT_DATA SET VALUE = 
             (SELECT  SUM(NVL(VALUE,0)) FROM CONTENT_DATA WHERE DATA_TYPE_ID IN(1,2)
                                        AND CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID) 
        WHERE CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID AND DATA_TYPE_ID = 3;  
    
        UPDATE CONTENT_DATA SET VALUE = (SELECT  SUM(NVL(VALUE,0)) FROM CONTENT_DATA WHERE DATA_TYPE_ID  IN(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
                                        AND CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID)
        WHERE CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID
        AND DATA_TYPE_ID = 10;           
        
        
        UPDATE CONTENT_DATA SET VALUE = (SELECT  SUM(NVL(VALUE,0)) FROM CONTENT_DATA WHERE DATA_TYPE_ID IN( 10,11,12,13,14)
                                            AND CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID)
        WHERE CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID
        AND DATA_TYPE_ID = 15;
    
    end loop;
    close your_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use cursors for this. I built a test case for you to see how it behaves, then you only need to change your three updates in the cursors for just three statements, without using cursors

Test Case

```
SQL> create table my_merge_test ( pk_id number, data_type_id number, content_id number, value number );

SQL> select * from my_merge_test ;

     PK_ID DATA_TYPE_ID CONTENT_ID      VALUE
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
         1            1          1          0
         2            2          1        100
         3            3          1        200
         4            3          1        120
         5            3          1        120
```

Now, let's see what you want to do on the first update:

```
UPDATE CONTENT_DATA SET VALUE = 
             (SELECT  SUM(NVL(VALUE,0)) FROM CONTENT_DATA WHERE DATA_TYPE_ID IN(1,2)
                                        AND CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID) 
        WHERE CONTENT_ID = item.CONTENT_ID AND DATA_TYPE_ID = 3;
```

For each content_id where data type is 1 or 2, you want to update the value to the sum of the value column ( 0 in case of null ) when the items are the same and data type is 3. For the others update the logic is the same , but with different values

Instead of using cursors, you can do the operation in one statement using with clause

```
SQL> update my_merge_test t
  2  set t.value = (
  3    with source as ( select  content_id, SUM(NVL(value,0)) as sum_value from my_merge_test where DATA_TYPE_ID IN(1,2)
                   group by  content_id
        )
  select h.sum_value
  from  source h
  where h.content_id = t.content_id and t.data_type_id = 3
) where t.data_type_id = 3
;  4    5    6    7    8    9   10

3 rows updated.

SQL> select * from my_merge_test ;

     PK_ID DATA_TYPE_ID CONTENT_ID      VALUE
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
         1            1          1          0
         2            2          1        100
         3            3          1        100
         4            3          1        100
         5            3          1        100

SQL>
```

Then the second update would be

```
update my_merge_test t
set t.value = (
  with source as ( select  content_id, SUM(NVL(value,0)) as sum_value from my_merge_test where DATA_TYPE_ID IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
               group by  content_id 
    )
  select h.sum_value 
  from  source h
  where h.content_id = t.content_id and t.data_type_id = 10
) where t.data_type_id = 10 
;
```

And the third would be

```
update my_merge_test t
set t.value = (
  with source as ( select  content_id, SUM(NVL(value,0)) as sum_value from my_merge_test where DATA_TYPE_ID IN ( 10,11,12,13,14)
               group by  content_id 
    )
  select h.sum_value 
  from  source h
  where h.content_id = t.content_id and t.data_type_id = 15
) where t.data_type_id = 15 
;
```

Replace the names with your tables and let me know if it does what you need.